# How to get the Default orange Highlight Effect for EditText

Tags: android

I've lost the Orange Highlight effect for EditText after implemented Round Corner effect using this code. Could someone tell me how to retrive the Highlight effect?

Thank you

round_corner_button_bg.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<gradient
    android:angle="45"/>

<padding
    android:left="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp" />

<solid
    android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

EditText.xml

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_button_bg"            
            android:password="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meen onClick orange effect try to surround code with '' properties and have color for onClicked and normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<gradient
android:angle="45"/>

<padding
android:left="10dp"
android:top="10dp"
android:right="10dp"
android:bottom="10dp" />

<solid
android:color="#ffdd00" />
</shape>
</item>


<item>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<gradient
android:angle="45"/>

<padding
android:left="10dp"
android:top="10dp"
android:right="10dp"
android:bottom="10dp" />

<solid
android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Comment: thank you. but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm talking about the Android default Orange highlight effect that highlights the border of the editText when selected.

Comment: than you can add `<stroke>` element inside `<item>` 

     `<stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ffdd00" />`

Comment: (And use #fff (white) for main color `<solid
android:color="#fff" />` )

Comment: problem is that it wouldn't stay. it only shows at click and disappears.

Comment: ok, now I realized your wish.. as you can see, in code above there are two `<item>` parameters, with and without parameter `android:state_pressed="true"` 

you probably want to have orange color when it is focused so try to add `<item android:state_focused="true" >` with same parameters(shape, corners...) mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make use of selector tag
you can learn about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

**EDIT**
Give the color you want when view is selected.

**EDIT** ***please customize it according to your usage***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize=["true" | "false"]
    android:dither=["true" | "false"]
    android:variablePadding=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"//YOUR ROUNDED CORNER XML
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_hovered=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_activated=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

Comment: but how do I implement it to my code? I want to use the round corder effect as well..

Comment: well you can add selector tags as well in your xml

Comment: it will be easier if you make two drawable with rounded corner one orange and another white and you can switch between those using selector

Comment: You can check the android resources under the sdk dir and use EditText backgrounds and selectors. I think api 2.2 uses the orange highlight effect.

Comment: @Chronos I Agree but he is not able to get it as he has used custom shape